# How to add a JQPlot class to hide all chart lines when page is loaded?

Tags: jquery, charts, primefaces, jqplot

I have too many series in my Primefaces JQPlot line charts app, and I want to load the chart with the lines already hidden; then, the user would click on the  desired legend to display the correspondent line in the chart ([see this example](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/pieChartsEnhancedLegend.php)).

The template.xhtml file:

```
<h:body onload="HideSeries()" >
    <!-- [unrelevant code ommited] -->
</h:body>

<script>
    function HideSeries() {
        $('#chartsFormID\\:lineChartID').toggleClass('jqplot-series-hidden');
    }
</script>
```

My index.xhtml file:

```
<h:form id="chartsFormID" >
    <p:accordionPanel multiple="false" dynamic="true" cache="true" >
        <p:tab title="myTab title">
            <p:chart type="line" id="lineChartID" model="#{bean.myChart}" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

Unfortunattelly, it's not working.

[image: An image for better understanding]

Can anyone, please, help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So effectively you ask how to run the HideSeries javascript on pageload?

Comment: No, this already works, but not as expected. I've reformulated the question to be more specific.

Comment: It works but not as expected??? Then it does not work...  Does any link from https://www.google.com/search?q=jqplot+how+to+hide+series+by+default help? Seems to be lots of info you do not refer to...

Comment: Sorry, but as you've asked: _So effectively you ask how to run the HideSeries javascript on pageload?_ . The HideSeries javascript pageload is effectively working. If you put inside the HideSeries function, for example, `alert('this function is called and effectively works when page loads')`, you will see the message in the screen, so the function works. But what I effectively need is to resolve what I'm asking in the question, that is hide the lines of the chart when page loads. What lots of info you refer to? Maybe that's why I'm asking here infos I don't know, expecting someone to help me?

Comment: In the links as a result from the google search, there are multiple related to turning off series by default, several even on stackoverflow. I don't use the feature you require, so I have no clear ready answer. But my fairly simple search resulted in multiple Q/A to investigate by you. That is my help to you for now. Investigate, keep note/track, provide feedback on why the questions did not help, and if none help, post all this in your question (see [ask]). Then it might be easier for us to help you (with an answer or a next step to investigate) if we have this additional information. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the class to all elements, try this:

```
$('tr.jqplot-table-legend td').toggleClass('jqplot-series-hidden');
```

Or you can trigger the click event on all elements:

```
$('tr.jqplot-table-legend td').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Hi @Javier! I've tested with both and using the second solution, when the page loads, the click event happens (I can see for a moment that the series get hidden and the legends get outlined)! But right after that, it's like the event click is triggered again, because the series get unhidden and the legends get  unselected. I tried to use both solutions together, or only the second solution too, but the same thing happens. If I use only the first solution, after pageload  the legend keeps outlined, but the lines of the chart doesn't get hidden. Do you know what it might be happening, please?

Comment: Its sound like the component are not completly loaded when you execute this trigger.
Why you hide all lines? Its for improve performance or for improve user experience?
If you make it for user experience, you can add two buttons to hide or show all lines manually.

The other solution is use a javascript timeout and wait while component is completly loaded

Comment: it' for improve both. I'm trying your tip to use buttons, but when I click the button, the series get hidden for a short moment, but right after that, the lines are shown up again. I've researched to try to resolve it, and foun a replot() method, but when I use it in the function, it reloads the whole page. Do you know what it might be ?